# TeamCity Environment dashboard with app version/build details

Tags: asp.net, deployment, continuous-integration, teamcity, devops

I'm looking for a dashboard or team city plugin that would help solve the following issue:

I work in a fairly large dev team, consisting of 4 delivery steams, each steam consisting of their own Dev & QA team. We use Team City for CI, and our DevOPS team have configured Team City so that we can deploy any successful CI build to any defined environment by simply selecting the build number, something like this:

[image]

It works quite well. We have quite a few environments, QA1 - QA5, demo, stage, prod etc...How we work within the team is that when QA's can own an environment, so what that means, they are in charge of deploying builds to QA environments, and they can deploy whatever build they wish to satisfy their current test case.

Example:

So lets say Dave is a QA in Dev Team 1: Dave will then claim temporary ownership of a QA environment, lets say QA2.

In another steam, the same process can happen, where a QA wishes to deploy a certain build, or feature branch (we use github), so test something, and therefor, the QA will claim temporary ownership of an environment, lets say QA3.

ATM, he use coloured spatchlers with the environment name written on it, and then the QA will stick that to his monitor. It's dorky and fun, works okay, but we are now looking for something more sophisticated. Why... well here is why:

ATM, we have no way of knowing who is owning what environment, and what build version is deployed to which environment. You need to go into Team City and see which build was deployed to a given environment, and then ask the team who is using that specific environment.

Surely there is already something out there that provides some sort of Dashboard, which feeds data from Team City, and then Displays each environment, with the Environment Name, the build version, or application version, and even who deployed it, and when.

Seeing as I am a developer, I'm happy to code something up for this, but before I do, I wanted to get some input on this from the stack overflow community :)

Cheers!

Comment: Sounds great although I think it might be easier (less maintenance) to hook up Octopus Deploy which has all this information out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 0):

This is way late, but I remember your question and I just found a bunch of TeamCtiy notification/visualization plugin list. Some of those might have what you want. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/TeamCity+Plugins